# I want to create a function in SQL that by input parameter my query condition is changed

Tags: sql

```
create function StudentExist(@nationalId nvarchar(10), @type as int)
returns bit
as
begin
    declare @i as int

    if(@type =1) 
        select @i = count(*) from BonyadShahidData..BonyadData where NationalCode = @nationalId and [type] = 'A'

    if(@type =2) 
        select @i = count(*) from BonyadShahidData..BonyadData where NationalCode = @nationalId and [type] = 'B'

    if(@type =3) 
        select @i = count(*) from BonyadShahidData..BonyadData where NationalCode = @nationalId and [type] = 'D'

    if(@i > 0)
        return 1

    return 0
end
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and **learn from it!**

Answer (score 0):

my answer will be as blunt as the question [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
create function StudentExist(@nationalId nvarchar(10), @type as int)
returns bit
as
begin
    declare @i as int

    if(@type =1) 
        select @i = count(*) from BonyadShahidData..BonyadData where NationalCode = @nationalId 
       and [type] = (case @type 
       when 1 then 'A'
       when 2 then 'B'
       when 3 then 'C'
       end)

    if(@i > 0)
        return 1

    return 0
end
```